# Page specific CSS in Volusion with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, overriding, volusion

New to designing on the Volusion platform and stuck after investigating the help topics on the support forms. I need to override a CSS style on all pages but my default.asp homepage. I am attempting to do this with javascript but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the demo for the site: http://v1330583.ovjk2w9aumkd.demo19.volusion.com/default.asp

I am attempting to modify my [#content rule](http://v1330583.ovjk2w9aumkd.demo19.volusion.com/v/vspfiles/templates/240/css/Template.css) by beginning with this Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[

  if (location.pathname == "/ProductDetails.asp") || 
  location.pathname.indexOf("-p/") != -1 || 
  location.pathname.indexOf("_p/") != -1)
  var onHomepage = true;

if(!onHomepage)
document.writeln("\n<style type='text/css'>content {
padding: 20px background-color: #fff}</style>\n\n"); 
//]]> </script>
```

Can anyone tell me

1. Where I should inset this code.
2. If there is a better way to do this.

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a much simpler way to do this in Volusion without Javascript. If you log in to your dashboard, go to 'Design->File Editor" and then click on the template HTML file (it will be under the heading 'Template Files', you'll be in the main template file for your site.

In between the `<body>` tags you'll just add a div with an id of "if_not_homepage" and the site will only read the contents of this div if not on the default.asp page. For example:

```
<div id="if_not_homepage">
    <style type="text/css">
        #content{
            padding:20px;
            background-color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

OR you could call a separate stylesheet completely from within this div (for example):

```
<div id="if_not_homepage">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/v/vspfiles/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/css/inner_style.css" />
</div>
```

If you place the stylesheet within the directory "/v/vspfiles/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/css/" you'll be able to edit the stylesheet from within the File Editor in the Volusion dashboard as well (like your other stylesheets).

Alternately, there is a div with an id of "if_homepage" that is read only if the user is on the default.asp (opposite of "if_not_homepage").

On a completely separate note, in your code above, you are missing either a class (.) or id (#) selector on 'content' in your CSS, so that may have something to do with it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a style tag, I think you are better off setting the style directly with jQuery (if the DOM is loaded) or writing out a link tag to a separate style sheet.